# MongoDB Pagination / Get page by Document Id

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB I have a collection of **messages**.

I've been using `.skip()` and `.limit()` to retrieve the **messages** that belong on the current page.

For example:

```
var pageSize = 20;
var pageNumber = 1;
db.messages.find({}).sort({ created_date: -1 }).skip(pageSize*(pageNumber-1)).limit(pageSize, callback);
```

My question is, if I have the **id** of a specific **message**, what is the best approach to retrieve it's "page" of results?

Comment: There's additional find conditions which need to be matched, but I've omitted them to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 3):

A solution could be retrieve the "created_date" of your doc by _id, then counting how many documents exists before him and dividing the number by your page size.

Example on the shell; if 'XXX' is the given Id then "page" would become the page of your record:

```
var pageSize = 20
vat tgId = 'XXX'
var when = db.messages.findOne({_id: tgId}, {created_date: 1})['created_date']
var page = Math.ceil(db.messages.find({created_date: {$lt: when}}).count() / pageSize)
```